# System.ObjectDisposedException not treated in facebook windows phone app

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

In this line appears error: "Cannot access a disposed object".

```
db._fbcontacts.InsertOnSubmit(new FacebookContactsList { Name = FBName });
```

What can a reason of it?

There is the method where I want to write name of user's account from facebook in localdatabase

```
public void LoadUserInfo()
     {
         using (FacebookDataContext db = new FacebookDataContext(DBConnectionstring))
         {
             FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
             fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
             {
                 var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
                 var FBName = String.Format("{0} {1}", (string)result["first_name"], (string)result["last_name"]);
                 db._fbcontacts.InsertOnSubmit(new FacebookContactsList { Name = FBName });
                 db.SubmitChanges();
             };
             fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback method is being called after the `FacebookDataContext` has been disposed.

This is the code that executes immediately

```
 using (FacebookDataContext db = new FacebookDataContext(DBConnectionstring))
 {
     FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
     // no callback method is being executed here!  
     fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
 }
```

then, sometime later when `GetTaskAsync` completes, the following is executed:

```
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();           
/*blah blah snip*/
db._fbcontacts.InsertOnSubmit(new FacebookContactsList { Name = FBName });
db.SubmitChanges();
```

But you can see from the first code block that, upon exiting the scope of the `using` statement, **db has already been disposed**.

Instead, you'll need to pull db out of the using block and dispose of it manually...

```
 public void LoadUserInfo()
 {
     FacebookDataContext db = new FacebookDataContext(DBConnectionstring);
     FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
     fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
     {
         try
         {
             /*blah fricken blah snipped */
             db.SubmitChanges();
         }finally{
             if(db != null) db.Dispose();
         }
     };
     fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
 }
```

Or you can pull the instantiation of the context inside of the event handler.

```
public void LoadUserInfo()
{
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient(App.AccessToken);
    fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
    {
        /*yadda mfing blah */
        using (FacebookDataContext db = new FacebookDataContext(DBConnectionstring))
        {
            db._fbcontacts.InsertOnSubmit(new FacebookContactsList { Name = FBName });
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
    };
    fb.GetTaskAsync("me");
}
```

Comment: It's very good answer.
But after first start processing current line db.SubmitChanges();
visual studio doesn't execute code. Without errors.

after second start app works